# How can I aggregate a list of string in a Linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to ultimately make a column in my MVC table have a string of OrderNumbers.  I can't seem to figure out have to have the collection of

```
public IEnumerable<OrderShippedListModel> GetRecentShippedOrders(string authenticatedUsername)
{
    User currentUser = new User().GetUser(authenticatedUsername);
    Order (from r in dc.Orders
            where r.Location.OrganizationID == currentUser.OrganizationID
            && r.CloseDate != null
            && r.ProductShipDate != null
            orderby r.LastModifiedDate descending
            select new OrderShippedListModel
            {
                ID = r.ID,
                OrderNumbers = r.Processes.Select(p=>p.OrderNumber),  //This needs to aggregate to a string
                Label = r.Label,
                Location = r.Location.Label,
                CreateDate = r.CreateDate,
                ProductShipDate = r.ProductShipDate,
                LastModifiedDate = r.LastModifiedDate,
                CloseDate = r.CloseDate
            }).Take(3);
}
```

Here's my class model

```
public class OrderShippedListModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Label { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Create Date")]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Modified Date")]
    public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product Ship Date")]
    public DateTime? ProductShipDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Close Date")]
    public DateTime? CloseDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Job Numbers")]
    public string OrderNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
OrderNumbers = string.Join("", r.Processes.Select(p=>p.OrderNumber)),
```

Answer (score 0):

Another is aggregate:

```
var s = r.Processes.Aggregate((accum, elem) => accum += elem.OrderNumber)
```

Comment: This is dramatically less efficient as it results in a *lot* of intermediate strings being created, thus consuming a lot of time allocating new character buffers and copying the same data between buffers over and over again.

Comment: I did not know it was that inefficient, thank you for pointing this out.